# jquery read and display in text field

Tags: jquery

I have a price calculator on my website. I would like jquery to pick the value on one box and send it to the other box in real time.

```
<form>
How much do you want to spend <input type="text" id="pricein" /><br />
This is how much you will spend<input type="text" id="priceout"/>
</form>
```

anybody know how this can be accomplished with jquery? This sounds like it might be easy but I'm learning it all slow but I'm learning. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#pricein").keyup(function() {
    $("#priceout").val($("#pricein").val());
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bumzd/)

Comment: whoops, should have refreshed the page before I posted my answer.

Comment: that was a working code but what about when the field is a read only field? How would you trigger a recalculation if a number in a field changes?  for example, The calculator im using uses formulas to populate some field. for example: #option1 + #option2 = #sum.   the div id ="sum" would be an html read field. How do I get it to dynamically readjust the number if it changes?

Answer (score 1):

You need the `val()` function:

```
var price = $('#pricein').val()
```

and to set the value:

```
$('#priceout').val(newValue);
```

You can read the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 1):

use keyup

```
$('#pricein').bind('keyup', function() 
    { 
        $('#priceout').val($(this).val()); 
    });​
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SerL9/)